# Laravel. How to return a links() pagination from the controller

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination

I'm trying to return a pagination from the controller using the link function, but I return an empty value. What could be the problem?

```
$models= Model::with('table2', 'table3')
->simplePaginate(5);
$str= "";
foreach($models as model){
       $str .= model['name'];
}
return response()->json([
        'rows' => $str,
        'links' => $models->links()
    ], 200);
```

laravel 5.5

If I return

```
return $models->appends(['rows' => $str])->links();
```

I get what I want. But when you try to return an array or a json, the link is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either the `toArray` or `toJson` methods, depending on what you need. For example::

```
$models = Model::with('table2', 'table3')->paginate(5)->toArray();
return [
    'models' => $models
];
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling the `simplePaginate` method, you will receive an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator.` These objects provide several methods that describe the result set. In addition to these helpers methods, the paginator instances are iterators and may be looped as an array. So, once you have retrieved the results, you may display the results and render the page links using `Blade:`

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($models as $user)
        {{ $user->name }}
    @endforeach
</div>

{{ $models->links() }}
```

Comment: The method you specified works when the page loads. I'm trying to return a new breakdown to the pages, that would change the old breakdown into pages. But the method that I use returns an empty string